# Git bash no longer allows typing into a Minecraft server console

Tags: bash, msys2

I've recently updated git bash to 2.35.1. I do Minecraft plugin/server development so am often using git bash to start and manage test servers in windows. Unfortunately I do not know what version I was on before.

Now when I started a server using `java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar` it boots, but I can't type anything into the console. I am completely locked out. Using CTRL+C will shutdown the server but it says "do you want to terminate the batch job" and hangs. I have to force quit the java process.

Before, I could type game console commands in without issue.

I've tried running git bash as administrator, no change. PowerShell doesn't work at all, it won't even show the output of the console after starting the jar.

When I stop the server from in-game, I get this error after it fully stops:

```
$ stop
bash: stop: command not found
```

Comment: "git bash" has nothing at all to do with git, except for being packaged alongside it on Windows. This is more likely to be a problem with msys2, the Windows compatibility layer it's compiled against, and a msys2 tag would be more applicable than a git tag.

Comment: Have you tried using `winpty`? (e.g. `winpty java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar`)

Comment: *"do you want to terminate the batch job"* Huh? Are you running a .bat file, rather than typing the command directly? What happens if you don't?

Comment: Yes it's running from a `.bat` file. When using the command directly, I still cannot type however CTRL+C exits the process

Comment: Using `winpty` hides the entire console output from me and doesn't even let me ctrl+c close the process. Had to kill it via task manager